# Pushing meteor to heroku error

Tags: heroku, meteor

I am trying to push a meteor app to heroku and I am getting this error. I am using the this buildpack heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/lirbank/meteor-buildpack-horse.git

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 268, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (254/254), done.
Writing objects: 100% (268/268), 3.84 MiB | 388.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 268 (delta 81), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Installing node
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: Downloading Meteor distribution
remote: ################################# 100.0%
remote: Meteor 1.2.0.2 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
remote:
remote: Now you need to do one of the following:
remote:   (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
remote:   (2) Run this command as root:
remote:         cp "/tmp/buildpack_de3e5x8d2f97747we2s5fb78436762066/meteor-      fkUa/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.9/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-   meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
remote: Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
remote: docs.meteor.com.
remote: -----> Bundling bundle
remote:
remote:
remote: While removing platforms:
remote: error: ios: platform is not in this project
remote: error: android: platform is not in this project
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected
```

Comment: no idea what a buildpack does, but this got to be related to the fact that as of 1.2, meteor no longer provides the ios and android platforms (sdks) itself. It uses the system provided installation instead. My money is on this buildpack not knowing about that yet and looking for the sdks in the .meteor folder.. just a guess.

Comment: I think that might be the problem, any idea of another way or buildpack I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. So I installed both ios and android platforms into my meteor app and setup heroku config var to BUILDPACK_PRELAUNCH_METEOR.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it worked for me like a charm.
I have a webapp and android app in the same folder.
the exact command line is:

heroku config:set BUILDPACK_PRELAUNCH_METEOR=1

Comment: Hi! Please note that SO is not exactly like a forum. The above is not an _answer_, but rather a _comment_. You will be able to comment on others' posts once you get more _reputation_. You will also be able to thank people by _upvoting_.